# Flask path routing parameter globs dot between two forward slashes

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to capture an url from a flask request. All works fine except when the url has a dot in between two forward slashes, for example: 
[http://met.no/Nyheter/./Fase+C:+Ekstremværet+Petra+pågår.b7C_xdrSX6.ips](http://met.no/Nyheter/./Fase+C:+Ekstremv%C3%A6ret+Petra+p%C3%A5g%C3%A5r.b7C_xdrSX6.ips)

The route used is below:

```
@app.route('/url/<path:url>', methods=['GET'])
def get_url(url):
    return url
```

The server is queried using curl:

```
curl localhost:5000/url/http://met.no/Nyheter/./Fase+C:+Ekstremværet+Petra+pågår.b7C_xdrSX6.ips
```

And the response:

```
http://met.no/Nyheter/Fase+C:+Ekstremværet+Petra+pågår.b7C_xdrSX6.ips
```

I understand flask is somehow resolving relative urls and ./ might mean the current directory, but how can I make it so the url is taken as is?

Comment: I don't see /url/ in your url

Comment: I have updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

After a response on the flask mailing list I realized some clients are trying to resolve the url before sending it through.

My version of curl seems to behave like that, and so does Chrome, but using CocoaRestClient for example returns the expected:

[http://met.no/Nyheter/./Fase+C:+Ekstremværet+Petra+pågår.b7C_xdrSX6.ips](http://met.no/Nyheter/./Fase+C:+Ekstremv%C3%A6ret+Petra+p%C3%A5g%C3%A5r.b7C_xdrSX6.ips)

Comment: Yes this is correct answer. In correct URL `/./` is completely unnecessary, dot means same directory. So clients remove it (incl CURL, Chrome and wget). One should not create such websites that rely on having dot in between, because http://a.com and http://a.com/./ are completely equvalent.